# Apps is reopening when I'm clicking opening it throw icon

Tags: android

I have an application with many screen and I've found some bug - when I'm pressing home button and then open app throw icon, than icon reopens. And it's working only with app that already signed for store. Non-signed version (debug) working just fine. Where can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add `launchMode="singleTop"` to the `<activity>` definition in the manifest. That should be enough to do what you want. It tells Android that it should use an existing instance of the Activity instead of creating a new one, if an instance of that Activity already exists at the top of the activity stack in the task.